# How can I optimize the below code with less number of line?

Tags: javascript

I have coded the below piece of code which handle the number bigger than 999 and add a comma to it. For example 1,000 and 1,000,000. Wheare as once the number increase the comma will be placed in the correct position. I used DRY principle and I feel still there is another easy way to handle it.
Now, I want to know if there is much better way than that I did.
Waiting for your opinion.

Thanks.

```
function seperate_num_by_comma() {

  var num = '199228754645.25',
    withOutComma = num.split('.'),
    addNewCommaAfter = 3,
    x = withOutComma[0].length % addNewCommaAfter,
    lenOfWithOutComma_0 = withOutComma[0].length,
    length_1 = withOutComma[0].length - x,
    starter = 0,
    wholeNumber = ' ';

  for (var i = 0; i < lenOfWithOutComma_0; i++) {

    function run_first_func() {
      wholeNumber += withOutComma[0].substr(starter, addNewCommaAfter);
    };

    function run_second_fun() {
      wholeNumber += withOutComma[0].substr(starter, addNewCommaAfter) + ",";
      starter += addNewCommaAfter;
      length_1 -= addNewCommaAfter;
    };

    if (x > 0) {
      if (length_1 == 0) {
        run_first_func();
        break;
      } else if (wholeNumber == ' ') {
        wholeNumber += withOutComma[0].substr(starter, x) + ",";
        length_1 -= addNewCommaAfter;
        starter = x;
      } else {
        run_second_fun();
      }
    } else if (x == 0) {
      if (length_1 == 3) {
        run_first_func();
        break;
      }
      run_second_fun();
    }
  }
  console.log(wholeNumber + '.' + withOutComma[1]);
}
seperate_num_by_comma();
```

Comment: you could first format it

Comment: In one line `function seperate_num_by_comma(){for(var e="199228754645.25".split("."),n=3,t=e[0].length%n,s=e[0].length,o=e[0].length-t,r=0,f=" ",i=0;i<s;i++){function u(){f+=e[0].substr(r,n)}function a(){f+=e[0].substr(r,n)+",",r+=n,o-=n}if(t>0){if(0==o){u();break}" "==f?(f+=e[0].substr(r,t)+",",o-=n,r=t):a()}else if(0==t){if(3==o){u();break}a()}}console.log(f+"."+e[1])}seperate_num_by_comma();`

Comment: This code only reformat my code. But Think there is no more way to simplify this code rather than what I did.

Answer (score 0):

## One Line:

165B minified version (no IE): `seperate_by_comma=t=>(x=(""+t).split("."),z=x[0].replace(/((\d{3})*?)(\.|$)/,"|$1").split("|"),x[0]=z[0]+z[1].replace(/(.{3})/g,",$1").slice(!z[0].length),x.join("."))`

OR 180B, IE-friendly: `seperate_by_comma=function(t){x=(""+t).split(".");z=x[0].replace(/((\d{3})*?)(\.|$)/,"|$1").split("|");x[0]=z[0]+z[1].replace(/(.{3})/g,",$1").slice(!z[0].length);return x.join(".")}`

## Explanation:

```
seperate_num_by_comma = function(number){//12345678.9
  var str = String(t);
  
  var withoutDot = str.split("."); //["12345678", "9"]
  
  var chunksOfThree = withoutDot[0].replace(/((\d{3})*?)(\.|$)/,"|$1");//"12|345678"
  chunksOfThree = chunksOfThree.split("|");//["12", "345678"]
  
  chunksOfThree[1] = chunksOfThree[1].replace(/(.{3})/g,",$1") //",345,678"
  
  if(chunksOfThree[0].length==0){
    chunksOfThree[1] = chunksOfThree[1].slice(1); //Fix for specific cases
  }
  
  withoutDot[0] = chunksOfThree[0] /*"12"*/ + chunksOfThree[1] /*",345,678"*/
  return withoutDot.join(".") //"12,345,678.9"
}
```